# ¿Cómo copiar el texto de un div al porta papeles y quitarle los puntos que tenga con JQuery?

Tags: jquery

Tengo el siguiente código

```js
function copyToClipboard(elemento) {
    var $temp = $("<input>");
    $("body").append($temp);
    $temp = $temp.val($(elemento).text().replace(/./g,""));
    $temp.select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
    $temp.remove();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="display: inline" id="num_document"> 1.145.649.815</div>
    <button onclick="copyToClipboard('#num_document')">Copiar Cédula</button>
```

La función me funciona copiando el texto y reemplazando el primer punto que encuentra pero lo que necesito es quitar todos los puntos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El carácter **.** tiene un significado para los `regex` *(un carácter arbitrario)* por lo cuál debes escaparlo.

```
$temp = $temp.val($(elemento).text().replace(/\./g,""));
```